# react native debug tools and techniques?

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a RN app in VS Code.  I'm using an Android AVD loaded from AS. My Android emulator is currently displaying the following error:  "Could not connect to development server."  I've seen the following debug steps listed as part of an answer to a similar question on SO:

- Open the in-app Developer menu.
- Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device.
- Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
- Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.

But I don't see a way to "Open the in-app Developer menu" via my AVD:

[image: My Android AVD]

Alternatively, I get the impression that react-devtools could potentially be used to help with debug purposes for a RN app.  When I launch the React Dev Tools, RDT states that I should add the following line of code to the top of the page that I want to debug, before importing React DOM:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8097"></script>
```

I'm not totally clear on this instruction.  My app has App.js and it has child components.  Am I supposed to insert this line of code as the first line of code in App.js or some other file?  I currently have this as the first line in App.js but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  Should I be using this hook differently or am I way off base in some other way here?

Comment: Press d on metro cli to see a developer menu pop on on Simulator/Device

Answer (score 0):

Please execute this command from the command: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Then run the project again.